# validar si hay datos para insertar en una tabla - laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy enredado con lo siguiente: tengo en mi funcion store un procedimiento almacenado mediante el cual hago un insert a 2 tablas, UNA TABLA OBLIGATORIA con datos, y otra tabla no obligatoria (ya que el usuario en la vista va generando filas de forma dinamica (en ciertas ocaciones, no siempre utilizara esta funcion), el insert me funciona bien con datos en ambas tablas, el tema es el siguiente: hay ocaciones en las cuales solo se insertara data en la primer tabla y en la segunda no, entonces en este caso ya no funciona el procedimiento almacenado. Como podria hacer para que se haga el insert en la primer tabla (obligatoria) y si hay datos, insertar en las segunda?

Asi tengo el store:

```
 public function store(Request $request){

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            //TABLA OBLIGTORIA (SE INSERTA SI O SI)
            $ejecutor = new EjecutorOt();
            $ejecutor->ot_id = $ot->id;
            $ejecutor->user_id = $request->get('ejecutor_id');
            $ejecutor->save();

            //ESTA SERIA LA TABLA EN LA QUE SE PUEDE O NO INSERTAR
            $material = $request->get('material');
            $cantidad = $request->get('cantidad');
            $existencia = $request->get('existencia');
            $cont = 0;
            while($cont < count ($material)){

                $materiales = new MaterialesOt();
                $materiales->material = $material[$cont];
                $materiales->cantidad = $cantidad[$cont];
                $materiales->existencia = $existencia[$cont];
                $materiales->ot_id = $ot->id;
                $materiales->save();
                $cont=$cont+1;
            }

            DB::commit();

            return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Orden de Trabajo generada y registrada con exito en el sistema');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            //return redirect()->route('home')->with('danger', 'No hemos podido registrar la solicitud...Intentelo mas tarde');
            return $e;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema? Te lanza algún error ese código?

Comment: si, al estar la tabla vacia se cae la transaccion

Comment: Y cual es el valor de `$material` cuando la tabla esta vacía?